# How to check whether a widget is currently clicked with the mouse?

Tags: c++, user-interface, gtkmm

I am looking for a way to check whether a Gtkmm entry is currently clicked with the mouse and if it is it should return true and otherwise false.

For example in the following image the widget in the middle should return true.

[image: Middle entry should return true and others should return false]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the property [`has_focus`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/unstable/classGtk_1_1Widget.html#a5026f738b414bb69c6fbd5d6a86e8feb). I cannot think of a situation in which the **Gtk::Entry** is being edited and it does not have focus. This property is not specific to **Gtk::Entry**, it is already present in **Gtk::Widget**.